# Number of unlabelled planar graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

What are the best known bounds on the number of non-isomorphic (unlabelled) planar graphs on $n$ vertices? Is there a simple proof that this number is at most exponential in $n$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple proof?  Sort of.

Let $t(n)$ be the number of plane triangulations with $n$ vertices.  Tutte 
[in ''A Census of Planar Triangulations,'' Canad. J. Math. 14 (1962), 21-38] 
found an [explicit formula](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/census-of-planar-triangulations/0C07F660D1000D2AF1DA9065E84FA3E4) for $t(n)$, implying that $t(n)\sim c n^\alpha \gamma^n$, where $\gamma=256/27$.  From here, the number $a(n)$ of non-isomorphic planar graphs is at most $2^{3n-6}t(n)$, also exponential.  There is an elegant [bijective proof](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~poulalho/Articles/PoSc_Algorithmica06.pdf) of Tutte's formula by Poulalhon and Schaeﬀer, but I wouldn't call it "simple".

For an exponential upper bound, there is a way to simplify the Poulalhon-Schaeﬀer proof.  Take a rooted plane triangulation $G$ (rooted means a vertex and an adjacent edge are labeled).  Denote by $T$ the depth-first search tree which is a planar tree with $n$ vertices and the same root.  The number of such trees is the Catalan number $C_{n-1}$. Now we need to triangulate the complement of $T$ in the plane,   which is bounded by the number of triangulations of $2(n-1)$-gon (twice the number of edges of $T$).  The latter is equal to $C_{2n-4}$.  Since $C_k<4^k$, putting these together gives an upper bound
$$a(n) < 2^{3n} \cdot 4^n \cdot 4^{2n} = 2^{9n}.$$
One can easily get rid of the $2^{3n}$ term by realizing that you are overcounting, but that requires a bit of an explanation and a tiny bit more background.

Answer (score 2):

There is a short proof of a stronger result by Norine, Seymour, Thomas, and Wollan that there is an exponential upper bound for every proper minor-closed class.

> For every proper minor-closed class of graphs $\mathcal G$, there exists a constant $c$, such that for every integer $n$, there are at most $n! c^n$ graphs in $\mathcal G$ with vertex set $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

This is the labelled version of your question, but as Igor mentions, the typical graph has trivial automorphism group, so we can divide by $n!$.

The paper is entitled *Proper minor-closed families are small* and can be downloaded [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895606000062/pdf?md5=030cd34e9a42991e44fe44f6d1c38875&pid=1-s2.0-S0095895606000062-main.pdf&_valck=1) or from Robin Thomas's [webpage](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/).

Answer (score 1):

The number is at most exponential, as you can see from [this nice survey.](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~fusy/Talks/PlanarGraphsUBC.pdf) (By Eric Fusy), as he also mentions, getting the precise asymptotics is nontrival (also, he talks about labelled graphs, but a general graph has trivial automorphism group, so you just divide by $n!.$

Comment: Thanks for the link Igor! However, I also don't see an easy way to see that a typical unlabelled graph admits n! distinct labellings. Also, I was hoping that there might be a simple proof of a weaker exponential bound...

Comment: I don't have the details at my fingertips, but generally what happens in planar graph classes is that any possible fixed induced subgraph occurs in a large random planar graph a linear number of times.  Wormald and others proved variations of this.  It implies that the typical planar graph has exponentially many (abstract) automorphisms.  However, there is a critical distinction between abstract isomorphism and embedding-preserving isomorphism that muddies the water here.